# Store data accessible to and editable for all users in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database

Is this possible to do:

- Create a (web) database where you can add data from a website either by `writing to  a file` or another method.
- Allow another user on the website to access this by `reading from a file` or another method.

If it is, I would like some information or code.
I Do not want to create an independent database because:
a) I just started learning `html5` and `javascript`
b) I do not know how, or have the resources to (I think, I'm just a user on a shared system without sudo access)

***OR***

Would I have to use something like **firebase**: (`https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html`)?

Comment: It is persistent data, how is it different from a normal db sits in the cloud which has access privelages for everyone? Sorry if i didn't understand.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Assuming the file you are talking about is stored on the server (otherwise other uses couldn't read it). But why wouldn't you just use a database?

Comment: A web database needs a computer to issue the requests and it is called a server. Computers serve data to each other,  they are mostly controlled by people. Internet is this. I think what you want is th internet itself or i misunderstand terribly :)

Comment: For example my computer constantly wants data from stack overflow, in one request it returns me your comment. Now i am writing and it will be saved on Stack Overflows server, for you to read. We are reading writing freely.

Comment: Changed it again. Sorry, I'm trying to explain something I barely know about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multi-user leaderboard in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948322/multi-user-leaderboard-in-javascript)

Comment: This is the 4th time youve asked the same question. You cant store and share data with multiple users unless you have an independent server to store the information on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Database , why would you need to write to a "file"?

What you really want is to create an application with a database. So search for tutorials, because there are hundreds available from google, in all web oriented languages you can imagine.

Or maybe you are looking for something [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820391/A-Very-Simple-Example-of-HTML-OFFLINE-Database-ind)?

Answer (score 1):

[IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

> IndexedDB is a transactional database system, like an SQL-based RDBMS. However, unlike SQL-based RDBMSes, which use fixed-column tables, IndexedDB is a JavaScript-based object-oriented database.